# Azure configuration advice

Tags: azure

I have a asp.net V2 website, which stores uploaded content to the file system and a SQL Server database (using Full-Text Search)

I'm trying to work out what the best configuration option would be for me on Azure?

I would like to have the site scalable, but if I do this how can I ensure that the uploaded content is shared across all the sites?

Also SQL Azure does not support Full-Text Searching, so does this mean I should setup a Virtual Machine and host it myself?

Comment: There probably isn't a "best configuration option" as this tends to be app-specific and up for debate. However: When talking specifically about Windows Azure SQL Database (formerly SQL Azure) vs SQL Server, and for multi-instance file access, those are fairly straightforward to answer (see my answer below).

Answer (score 1):

For your database, you'll want to run SQL Server in a Virtual Machine, as you'll then get all functionality of SQL Server, including FTS. It's very simple to get up and running with SQL Server VM's, as there's a gallery image with SQL Server preinstalled.

Regarding your file system storage: This won't scale to multiple instances. You'll need another mechanism for storage. Typically this would be Blob Storage, but... it depends on what you're doing with the files. If you're just serving / storing content (you mentioned uploaded content), this works great, and it's accessible across many instances. If, on the other hand, it's some type of file-based database or index, that won't really work well.

If you need to do some type of local processing on the files (e.g. photo or movie rendering), you can easily copy a blob's contents to a local VM disk, process the file with typical drive paths, then upload the results to another blob.